Pedometer package's stepCountStream, listened in a Foreground Service does not trigger onData when phone is sleeping
I'm developing a Flutter app using pedometer package to track steps of the user. I want to count steps when app is closed as well, so I used flutter_background_service package as well in order to use foreground service on Android.
Basically this is my setup Background Service initialization logic (which is basically configured to use onStart method mentioned below):
    Future<void> initializeBackgroundService() async {
        final service = FlutterBackgroundService();
        await service.configure(
            androidConfiguration: AndroidConfiguration(
                onStart: onStart,
                autoStart: true,
                isForegroundMode: true,
                notificationChannelId: 'my_foreground',
                initialNotificationTitle: 'AWESOME SERVICE',
                initialNotificationContent: 'Initializing',
                foregroundServiceNotificationId: 888,
            ),
            iosConfiguration: IosConfiguration(
                autoStart: true,
                onForeground: onStart,
                onBackground: onIosBackground,
            ),
        );
    }

onStart method (method called when foreground service is started):
    @pragma('vm:entry-point')
    Future<void> onStart(ServiceInstance service) async {
        DartPluginRegistrant.ensureInitialized();
        if (service is AndroidServiceInstance) {
            service.on('setAsForeground').listen((event) {
                service.setAsForegroundService();
            });
            service.on('setAsBackground').listen((event) {
                service.setAsBackgroundService();
            });
        }
        service.on('stopService').listen((event) {
            service.stopSelf();
        });
        await activatePedometer(service);
    }

And the content of activatePedometer method:
    Future<void> activatePedometer(ServiceInstance service) async {
        Stream<StepCount> pedometerStream = Pedometer.stepCountStream;
        var subscription = pedometerStream.listen((stepCount) async {
            print("STEP DATA LISTENED!!!");
        }
        Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) async {
            print('TIMER: ${DateTime.now()}!!!');
        });
    }

listen callback of stepCountStream is called in the following scenarios:

When app is open
When app is minimized
When app is closed
When phone lock screen is shown

And as you can see in the code, "STEP DATA LISTENED!!!" is printed on debug console.
But when phone is locked and screen goes black, this callback is not triggered even when user takes steps. When user uses lock button to show lock screen, it is triggered again. I want to be able to read step data even when phone is sleeping (locked and screen is black).
Has anyone encountered a problem similar to this? Is there anything I can do to ensure listen callback is triggered even when phone is sleeping (locked and screen is black)?
Device: Huawei P9 Lite
OS: Android 7.0
I wanted to see if this is a foreground service issue, that's why I added the following:
    Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) async {
        print('TIMER: ${DateTime.now()}!!!');
    });

"TIMER: 2024-04-27 21:58:00.657213!!!" is printed every second even when phone is locked and screen goes black. So it's clearly not a foreground service issue.
I also checked if pedometerStream (in activatePedometer method) isPaused and it was not paused.

I am very much interested in how to do this as well. Is it even possible?
